# What does "Professional Developers" mean in Stack Overflow Developer Survey?

Tags: support, survey, survey-2019

I am just studying [Developer Survey Results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=announcement-banner&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019#technology) and the following question rose - what does "Professional Developers" mean?

The reason of this question are the results of the Survey. For example, most popular technology of Professional Developers is JavaScript (69.7%). And for Frameworks, libraries and tools, the most popular is Node.js @ 50.4% and the most popular RDBMS is MySQL with 52.0%.

And I can't understand how Professional Developers develop professional applications for state organizations, for banks, for industry, transport, logistic enterprise etc using these technologies.

Could anyone explain the meaning of this term?

Comment: I always took it to mean as "has a career/living doing it" (ie gets paid for it) rather than "I enjoy doing it but I do something else for a living"... why wouldn't any of those technologies be applicable for the things you mention anyway? Someone's gotta write front-end stuff for websites, someone's gotta write back-end stuff to handle things and there's always internal projects of all sorts within organisations even if they're not part of the stack providing the publicly accessible bits...

Comment: In the end, it's what responders *believe* it means. I don't think they'll drift far from the dictionary definition: "engaged in a specified activity as one's main paid occupation rather than as an amateur".

Comment: Why are you surprised that those technologies might be used for the industries that you mention?

Comment: It's clearly related to our job. Like Jean Reno in the movie "Léon: The Professional". We kill people for a living and you have to refers as Professional. Don't forget the capitalisation,

Comment: _"most popular technology of Professional Developers is JavaScript (69.7%)"_ Is a confirmation of the previous statement. But it's still unclear if it's the cause or the effect.

Answer (score 10):

I'm the data scientist who worked on this survey. This year, we clarified what we mean by developer on the survey itself. For those who didn't take the survey or who don't remember, this is how the question about professional identity was framed:

**Which of the following best describes you today? Here, by "developer" we mean "someone who writes code."**

- I am a developer by profession
- I am not primarily a developer, but I write code sometimes as part of my work
- I used to be a developer by profession, but no longer am
- I am a student who is learning to code
- I code primarily as a hobby
- None of these

Respondents who chose the first two options were included in the "professional developer" categories.

Comment: Which of these answers were considered professional developer? First 3? Same but including 5? All but the last?

Comment: I'd respectfully submit that as currently put, this does not answer the question. Missing information: which of the choices translate(s) into  "Professional Developers" in the results?

Comment: Ah, my apologies that it was not clear! I added more detail.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I disagree with your criteria for "professional developer".  I picked #2 as my choice as it best describes me here, but I would never consider myself a professional developer

Comment: Where would a grad student fall under? Does it matter if they're employed as a researcher full-time/part-time/not at all? Master's vs. PhD? etc.

Comment: @Mehrdad This was the first question on the survey, and grad students were certainly free to identify as they wish. We see some distinction between grad students in CS and those in other areas (sciences, engineering, etc) but many grad students identified more as developers or people who code as part of their work rather than students. As someone who went to grad school myself, this makes sense to me and my experience.

Answer (score 9):

"[Professional](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/professional)" === this is your profession.

Front-end and e.g. android app developers are as professional as back-end ones if this is their primary occupation.

Comment: Honestly the only correct answer would be for one of the survey designers to indicate what they mean by the term.

Comment: @rjzii [speak of the devil...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382648/what-does-professional-developers-mean-in-stack-overflow-developer-survey/382725#382725)

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you're a scientist. You study ... plate tectonics or something; geology is your primary love. Your business card says geologist, and that's what you went to school to become.

BUT, you use a *ton* of Python to rig up all your field sensors and poll them for data, and to make sense of that data, you use lots of jQuery and R.

Professionally, you're a *scientist*, but you could just as easily be a programmer. It allows people to participate more specifically regarding the role that programming plays in their profession, up to and including it *being* their profession.

I use R and Python every day, but professionally, I'm more in the public relations bucket. But that shouldn't make me think the survey *isn't* for me :)

Comment: jQuery has infected the sciences...