# Data science time! April 2019 and salary with experience

Tags: discussion, survey-2019, data

Welcome to April's installment of the regular, bite-size, data-focused updates I am sharing with Meta! You can check out [previous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380220/data-science-time-february-2019-and-opinion-with-experience) [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378674/data-science-time-january-2019-and-views-to-answers) by me if you like, as well as [March's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381508/ux-research-time-march-2019-and-the-user-profile-and-settings) from my coworker Donna.

Yesterday, we launched the results of the [2019 Developer Survey](http://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019); you can read about everything from hours worked per week to issues around underrepresented groups in tech. During my time analyzing the survey data, I found more interesting results than we had space to include in the main report. This month seems like a great time to share one of those here with you all on Meta!

### Let's talk MONEY.

The salary information that we gather in our annual survey is some of the most valuable data in the whole thing, because this gives us a specific insight into our industry that we can't really collect in any other way. We can combine salary data with other characteristics of respondents to build a deep understanding of how developers earn. We use exactly this kind of information for the statistical modeling behind our [salary calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary), which will be updated in the upcoming months to use 2019 data.

Globally, how do we we see experience, salary, and developer role interact?

[image]

This plot shows the global median annual salary in USD on the y-axis; check out the [methodology section](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#methodology) of the main survey report for details on how we converted local currencies used by respondents to USD. The x-axis shows years that respondents have been coding professionally. For this plot, I chose four developer roles to highlight from across the industry, although we do have this data for many other roles from [designers to mobile developers](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-roles).

What are some things we can notice from this plot?

- As expected, more experienced people who code earn more, across the board.
- Salary typically is increasing fastest for early-career developers.
- Folks who work in data and DevOps are high earners, [not only in absolute terms](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#work-_-salary-by-developer-type), but also at a given experience level.
- Data science and DevOps roles are somewhat newer, at least framed in those ways with those titles, but we see that some of the people in those roles have been coding for a long, long time. These folks earn a lot.
- The relative shift in salary from early to mature career stage for back-end developers compared to system administrators is interesting, and I would love to know how this develops moving forward.

It's important to remember when looking at a plot like this that we are seeing it **today**; it's a bit more like looking into the past than looking into the future, in terms of salary trends.

What are your thoughts? This analysis uses survey data that will be publicly available under the [Open Database License](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/) soon, so you can reproduce this for yourself if you like, or dig into further details. In the meantime, you can check out our [previous years' results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/). Do you have topic ideas for future data science explorations?

Comment: Are there any plans to bring a social scientist or survey methodologist on board to help with the design of the 2020 survey? The data science aspect of the survey is neat, but practically speaking it's of limited value to the broader research community - who would love to get their hands on a large sample like this! - due to some methodological issues with the design.

Comment: @rjzii We do have folks with training and experience in those areas already on board, including me. We are committed to improving the survey and absolutely open to specific feedback about survey design, though! We're always interested in best practices in survey methods for opt-in non-probability surveys, observational studies, etc.

Comment: It's good to hear that there are members of the team that have some background is survey methods! Speaking as a peer reviewer (my PhD training is in the field of in computational social science, which included survey methods), I noticed a lot of issues with the construction of the survey instrument when I took it. Last year was also problematic since you should not change the instrument after you start collecting data either. There's also been some questions about terminology (e.g., [professional developer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382648)) which can result in errors.

Comment: In terms of specific problems with the instrument, I'd have to sit down with it to really dig through it my responses would be different if I was looking at it from a research perspective (e.g., identifying your variables, sources of bias, etc.) versus a respondent. As I'm sure you are aware, one of the biggest issues facing researchers is getting enough data to address RQs so an annual survey from a high profile site could be a huge boon to research.

Comment: Going back to the "professional developer" again real quick though, I don't recall seeing it defined on the instrument and it doesn't seem to be on the insights page. That really needs to be done since it is important to interpreting the data and there is a cultural component to what that means. Misinterpretation of that by respondents could really skew the interpenetration and should have come up during the pretest and pilot phase of instrument development.

Comment: That particular question did not surface as a problem when we tested the survey during UX research sessions or when we piloted the survey with 1000+ respondents before its broader fielding. I added the actual wording from the instrument to the other question, to clarify: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382725/5468471

Comment: Yes, saw the update on the question and spelling out the meaning on the instrument is good. Has there been a write-up of the instrument design process at SE yet? I'd (and some of my colleagues talking about the data) would really like to see how SE is addressing some of the internationalization issues.

Comment: We've only written about this [very generally](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/02/07/how-the-2019-stack-overflow-developer-survey-came-to-be-and-your-last-chance-to-take-it/), but also talk about [currencies and other geographical issues here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#methodology). If you have a specific question, I'm happy to answer it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the first link, so thank you for that. The second is useful for evaluating the team's interpretation, but for research I suppose the biggest thing would be when the data gets released it would be nice to have an explanation of the RQs that the team is trying to address. The data from opt-in non-probability surveys isn't very useful without an understanding of the RQs since those inform the IV and DV that are used in the instrument. Given that this survey format is going to be biased, one challenge in using the data for research is controlling for that bias.

Comment: What would be interesting is: How has the salary developed over the last 5 years?

Comment: Sorry if this looks like a stupid question, but is it monthly or annual?

Comment: It is annual salary.

Comment: I wish $120,000 per month was a reasonable salary expectation for someone doing my job...

Comment: "_Do you have topic ideas for future data science explorations?"_. While I agree the subject of this post is pertinent (using data from the annual survey wish was just published) I also want to ask when will there be a post with a topic chosen by the community? So far, it seems 'closing questions' (and its derivatives) is a winner, isn't it? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please do such a graph per programming language, not just developer type? I know the survey results page has something similar, but unfortunately it's just a point plot of the average experience vs average salary.

Comment: How do you actually convert salaries? Maybe it's just me, but I don't see where in the methodology you explain how you convert salaries from outside the US to match those in the US. I mean, I'm from Uruguay, and I could answer the survey saying I have a high salary of USD40.000 per year, and that would look like a student in your graph. That's what I understand at least, I can ask a separate question if it's needed

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Some details [are here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#methodology) but the general gist is that respondents told us their country, currency, and salary in that local currency. We converted all responses to USD to do worldwide medians.

Comment: I think @CamiloTerevinto is right; there must have been either adjustment for purchasing power, or a relatively low number of respondents from countries with lower costs of living, so that the median is mainly driven by high-cost countries.  Aggregating salary in dollars across countries doesn't make a whole lot of sense due to varying costs of living, taxation, health care systems, etc., when most people want to see how they stack up within their own country and line of work.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Concur. Even within the United States the salaries are kind of meaningless. Someone in the Midwest making $100k is going to be *a lot* better off than someone in Silicon Valley making the same. However, such adjustments are difficult to do unless you rely upon data sets that someone else builds out that contain the relevant adjustments.

Comment: Anyone else enjoy the uptick in salary for back end devs and devops specialists, once you hit 20 years? :)

Comment: *Folks who work in data and DevOps are high earners* - only in areas that have the infrastructure otherwise we end up swapping our hats to data engineering and backend development so much that we make just the same as them (I've seen the general comments on localization - I still find it heavily skewed)

Comment: Can you upload the raw dataset to kraggle or any other place so we can do our analysis on them ? maybe mixing them with other economic data to get more meaningful numbers

Comment: This analysis would be more accurate if it was normalized by the PPP or any other index that reflects the real value instead of the nominal.

Comment: Curious that you have back end, but no full stack, ui or other designation? Why these 4 specific silos? Are they the most highly represented? Can they be broken down further?

Comment: In South Africa your average starting salary is around $15000 for whichever role. This survey just made me depressed. I guess this is what global companies mean by saying: 'That salaries around here are very competitive'.

Comment: I think it would be better to use an averaged exchange rate (from-to), rather than the exchange rate, to eliminate the comission taken by the bureau/bank.  This could raise foreign salaries by 1-2% compared to US.

Comment: in India average starting salary is around 2000$, this survey makes no sense as it is not applicable to all countries.

Comment: Why is this still pinned on the main page? It's pretty clearly run it's course.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Although the absolute values of salary certainly vary from country to country, we see these trends with experience and developer role across the globe. That's what I was looking to share here!

Comment: @TheCoder I chose these three because they span some of the highest to lowest developer roles and get a lot of interest in the software industry right now. The question about developer role was framed more broadly and you can dig more deeply into this data either for yourself using our data release or with our salary calculator: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary

Comment: @sino We release the data from the Developer Survey each year, a number of weeks after the initial report is launched. You will see this year's data released in May, and can find previous years' here: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey